# How to make the code search for a keyword inside a user input java

Tags: java, input

Here is my code sorry for the messiness. Is there a code that will basically process the user input and select a keyword "mood has ... inside" (I know its not even close).

```
package Project_Folder;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Testing2 {

    private static Scanner input;

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String mood;
        String f;

        System.out.println("Describe how you are feeling?");
        mood = input.next();
        if (mood has sad inside){
            System.out.println("I hope you will feel better later");
        } else if (mood has wierd inside){
            System.out.println("I hope you will feel better later");
        } else if (mood has happy inside){
            System.out.println("cool you are lucky I cannot feel emmotions"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[String.contains(String str)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

```
string.contains("whatever");
```

Comment: For a more flexible check, you might want to mention regular expressions.

Comment: How do you specify which string?

Comment: string is the input string, `mood` in your case. "whatever" is the string to find, which was only an example. In your case if would be `if (mood.contains("sad"))`,  `else if (mood.contains("weird"))`, etc

Comment: But it does not work if someone anwsers "very sad" so thats the problem the whole point is that it can dissect the string,

Comment: It should work https://ideone.com/55Xb53. Note this is case sensitive, so you might want to apply .toLowerCase() to your string before checking.